# How to add a condition inside $lookup in MongoDb .aggregate()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

**persons collection:**

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96"),
  "gender": "male",
  "name": {
    "title": "mr",
    "first": "victor",
    "last": "pedersen",//... more properties
}
```

**persondetails collection:**

```
{
      "_id": ObjectId("5f3a91e68b1c26e68f9ed3ad"),
      "country": "India",
      "personid": ObjectId("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96")
}
```

Get documents from persons along with associated persondetails where associated country in persondetails is "India

**So if out of 10 persons only 3 are from India. I should get 3 person documents in resultset along with their associated persondetails**

**Query:**

```
 [
    {
      "$match": {
      "$or": [
         
        {
          "$expr": {
            "$eq": [
              "$gender",
              "male"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "totalCount": [
        {
          "$count": "value"
        }
      ],
      "data": [
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "fname": "$name.first",
            "lname": "$name.last",
            "dobage": "$dob.age",
            "registeredAge": "$registered.age"                
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            "name.first": 1
          }
        } ,
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "persondetails",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "personid", // how to add where clause in this lookup?
            "as": "persondetail" 
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

**EDIT:**

https://mongoplayground.net/p/3vBs6Frt-aK

**Expected Result:**

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96"),
        "fname": "victor",
        "lname": "pedersen",
        "persondetail": [
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5f3a91e68b1c26e68f9ed3ad"),
            "country": "India",
            "personid": ObjectId("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96")
          }
        ]
      }],
    "totalCount": [
      {
        "value": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: You don't need a where clause there but an extra $match stage after $lookup to filter out people you don't like to see in the result.

Comment: Wouldnt that be bad for performance? @AlexBlex

Comment: Most likely yes. Would you notice the difference? It depends. Premature optimisation is considered a counterproductive practice yet if it is critical you'd better test it on your dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a second [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) syntax which allows you to specify custom filtering condition:

```
{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "persondetails",
        "let": { person_id: "$_id" },
        "pipeline": [
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $and: [
                            { $eq: [ "$$person_id", "$personid" ] },
                            { $eq: [ "$country", "India" ] },
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "as": "persondetail" 
    }
}
```

EDIT:
You also need to add $match to filter out people with empty `persondetail` and if you want this to be included in your count then you need to run $facet as the last operation:

```
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "$or": [ {"$expr": { "$eq": [ "$gender", "male" ] } } ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "fname": "$name.first",
                "lname": "$name.last",
                "dobage": "$dob.age",
                "registeredAge": "$registered.age"                
        }
    },    
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "persondetails",
            "let": { person_id: "$_id" },
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and: [
                                { $eq: [ "$$person_id", "$personid" ] },
                                { $eq: [ "$country", "India" ] },
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "as": "persondetail" 
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            persondetail: { $ne: [] }
        }
    },
    {
        $facet: {
            totalCount: [ { $count: "value" } ],
            data: [ { $sort: { "name.first": 1 } },  ]
        }
    }
]
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1f4isMN2560)

Comment: And this will filter out persons? or persondetails?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working. I replaced my lookup with yours and I am getting wrong output

Comment: this is @mickl answer, its working as you described

Comment: it is also returning where persondetail is empty @varman

Comment: if there is no data to join, then it will give you empty array

Comment: @SamuraiJack here's a working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/jbpCkxIDpPN

Comment: @mickl see my playground, I have added another item to persons collection

Comment: Thank you @SamuraiJack I have modified my answer, hope it helps now :)

Comment: @mickl that is brilliant! If you do not mind mikl, could I please ask you for 2 mins of your time to answer a couple of questions around it?

Comment: @SamuraiJack sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220880/discussion-between-samuraijack-and-mickl).